# refreshing entire page from within an updatepanel

Tags: c#, asp.net

Here's my situation.  I have a web forms page, and it's getting annoying when the entire page scrolls to the top every time you click a control, so I'm trying to apply update panels to my page.

The submit button may or may not be click-able depending on whether or not the contents of individual update panels are in a proper state.

When the submit button is clicked, It can potentially affect any of the controls on the page.

I understand that I can do some of this with the `<triggers>` tag element of the update panel, but I don't want to have to put everything on the page into an update panel with it's own trigger, I'd rather that the submit button just reload the entire page.

For the sake of simplicity I've put together a sample project to represent my page.  It has a "reset" button, to represent the "submit" button.

The Master page:

```
<%@ Master Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Site.master.cs" Inherits="WebApplication1.SiteMaster" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
    <link href="~/Styles/Site.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="HeadContent" runat="server">
    </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
</head>
<body>
    <form runat="server">
    <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager" runat="server" EnablePartialRendering="true"  />

    <div class="page">
        <div class="header">
            <div class="title">
                <h1>
                    My ASP.NET Application
                </h1>
            </div>
            <div class="loginDisplay">
                <asp:LoginView ID="HeadLoginView" runat="server" EnableViewState="false">
                    <AnonymousTemplate>
                        [ <a href="~/Account/Login.aspx" ID="HeadLoginStatus" runat="server">Log In</a> ]
                    </AnonymousTemplate>
                    <LoggedInTemplate>
                        Welcome <span class="bold"><asp:LoginName ID="HeadLoginName" runat="server" /></span>!
                        [ <asp:LoginStatus ID="HeadLoginStatus" runat="server" LogoutAction="Redirect" LogoutText="Log Out" LogoutPageUrl="~/"/> ]
                    </LoggedInTemplate>
                </asp:LoginView>
            </div>
            <div class="clear hideSkiplink">
                <asp:Menu ID="NavigationMenu" runat="server" CssClass="menu" EnableViewState="false" IncludeStyleBlock="false" Orientation="Horizontal">
                    <Items>
                        <asp:MenuItem NavigateUrl="~/Default.aspx" Text="Home"/>
                        <asp:MenuItem NavigateUrl="~/About.aspx" Text="About"/>
                    </Items>
                </asp:Menu>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="main">
            <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="MainContent" runat="server"/>
        </div>
        <div class="clear">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="footer">

    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

The default page:

```
<%@ Page Title="Home Page" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Site.master" AutoEventWireup="true"
    CodeBehind="Default.aspx.cs" Inherits="WebApplication1._Default" %>



<asp:Content ID="HeaderContent" runat="server" ContentPlaceHolderID="HeadContent">

</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ID="BodyContent" runat="server" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent">

    <asp:Label runat=server Text="This lable represents things not in update panels" ID="label1"></asp:Label>

    <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat=server>
        <ContentTemplate>
            <table>
                <tr>
                    <td><asp:Button ID="button1" runat="server" OnClick="Button1_click" Text="Button 1" /></td>
                    <td><asp:TextBox ID="textBox1" runat="server" Text="StartText" Enabled="false" /></td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </ContentTemplate>
    </asp:UpdatePanel>

    <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel2" runat=server>
        <ContentTemplate>
            <table>
                <tr>
                    <td><asp:Button ID="button2" runat="server" OnClick="Button2_click" Text="Button 2" /></td>
                    <td><asp:TextBox ID="textBox2" runat="server" Text="StartText" Enabled="false" /></td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </ContentTemplate>
    </asp:UpdatePanel>

    <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanelReset" runat=server>
        <ContentTemplate>
            <asp:Button ID="reset" runat="server" OnClick="Reset_click" Text="reset" />
        </ContentTemplate>
        <Triggers>
            <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="button1" EventName="click" />
            <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="button2" EventName="click" />
        </Triggers>
    </asp:UpdatePanel>

</asp:Content>
```

The code behind

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Xml.Linq;

namespace WebApplication1
{
    public partial class _Default : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        protected void Button1_click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            textBox1.Enabled = !textBox1.Enabled;
            reset.Enabled = !textBox1.Enabled && !textBox2.Enabled;
        }

        protected void Button2_click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            textBox2.Enabled = !textBox2.Enabled;
            reset.Enabled = !textBox1.Enabled && !textBox2.Enabled;
        }

        protected void Reset_click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            textBox1.Text = "StartText";
            textBox2.Text = "StartText";
            label1.Text = "reset button clicked";
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add a PostBackTrigger to the last UpdatePanel.

```
<asp:PostBackTrigger ControlID="reset" />
```